# How to defend my point when my questions just get deleted in few hours?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14451/virtualization-server-for-software-developers-home-office) and attempted to follow instructions - first not to ask tech support, and second, show what I have done myself - while avoiding too many words. The question got immediately deleted, because I was supposedly asking tech support. Fine, as yours truly in not native English speaker and well, not a literary genius, lets try again.

To avoid specific details and concentrate on one thing only, I then asked what kind of motherboard to buy - that would be compatible with hardware hypervisor. [With this reformulated question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/pc-grade-motherboard-for-virtualization-server) I attempted to avoid going into too much detail (that would be tech support). Unlucky me, deleted again as having too broad requirements.

Unfortunately, there is no way to be more specific. Because I have to choose PC motherboard that is compatible with bare metal hypervisor. It is **one** thing I have to choose based on **one** limiting factor. Is it possible at all or should I go and buy an actual server-grade machine? I have no idea. However, there are people here who know. I have even some in my phonebook and they will be less intimidating to contact than posting a question here.

I mean, why just delete a question, of all possible correction methods? Can you put it on hold, or suggest OP to rephrase?

I totally appreciate that someone is trying to run tight ship here. Ask for suggestions for a thingy with blue knob and you get your answer. Otherwise, off you go.

Comment: There are a terrible amount of off-topic questions here. It is because people, particularly first-posters, do not know that this site is only for looking a specific hardware. If you plan to defend your (maybe later deleted) question on the meta, it is useful if you save the question - yet before deletion - on the https://archive.org .

Comment: Somehow make more obvious that you are looking for a hardware. I see a huge amount of new questions in the first-posts queue, and mostly I have no hearth to vote them all to close, rather I click "skip", but.. I don't know, what to do. On this site, even a single vote is eligible for a question closure, and mods have the habit to delete closed questions on the spot. This is obviously because the huge amount of mistargeted questions. I do not see your original question, but as you write here, I believe it is border-case on-topic. It is probably on-topic on the https://superuser.com,

Comment: maybe it is on-topic also on the https://serverfault.com (if you are building some professional virtualization solution). However, these sites are explicitly **not** for hardware recommendations, so there you should ask focusing on the "how to know if..." side. Here you should focus on the "which motherboard is..." side.

Comment: @peterh Sure, this was not right place to post my question. I was however curious of the method this place is run and why. I'm not still sure I understand, but thanks for taking your time to explain.